# Change regional settings on pre-Windows 2008 / Vista

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-registry, service-accounts

How do you change the regional settings of the various system accounts (local system, local service and network service) on older versions of Windows ?

I can only find the page on [MSDN](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Apply-regional-and-language-settings-to-reserved-accounts) that refers to this feature, but it's only applicable to Vista or later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's quite simple.

In Windows 2003, just log in as an administrator, open the tool from panel control, and in the third secction, check "apply this to all users" (after changing it to the one you need).

After restarting, any user that logs, or any account who runs a service, will run with the same setting u have configured.

I suppose in 2000 will work too, they're similar.

Comment: You know I looked at the Regional dialog, saw that option "All all settings to the current user account and to the default user profile" and discounted it, because it didn't mention it would also affect the system accounts, which is explicit in 2008. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon ... the system account is still in US, rather than UK, so I'm getting the dates in MM/DD/YYYY format  :-(

Comment: Well, that way worker for me in my servers, I changed from US to SP without problems. Anyway, that conf is usually stored in the "documents adn settings" folder. What I would do is to delete the folder of the account u need to change, modifi again the regional dialog, restart, log as that account (new folder will be created) and make a "date" from a "cmd" window. Try and told us.

Answer (score 0):

By [Toomanyhat](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33829058/iis7-changing-the-regional-settings-for-the-network-service-accoun.aspx).

Of additional note is that the Application Pool Identity NETWORKSERVICE
applies to both the DefaultAppPool and the Classic .Net AppPool

But in a classic ASP web page a VBScript calling for
FORMATDATETIME(Date(),2) did not correct with a Short time setting to the

```
SID: S-1-5-20
Name: NT Authority
Description: Network Service
```

In order for the Classic .Net AppPool to respond it needed the following SID
adjusted as well.

```
SID: S-1-5-18
Name: Local System
Description: A service account that is used by the operating system.
```

for good measure I made the same change here

```
SID: S-1-5-19
Name: NT Authority
Description: Local Service
```

this is consistent with the value under

Navigate to `HKEY_USERS\.Default\Control Panel\International`